# HTMLPurifier addElement syntax

Tags: php, kohana, element, htmlpurifier

I want to let users to use tag `<vid>Link</vid>`, so I've added "vid" to HTML.AllowedElements in config of purifier, so it throws me an error telling that its dont know such tag and pointing me to http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html
So I've tried to use the following code:

```
$config = $config->getHTMLDefinition(TRUE);
$config->addElement('vid', 'Block', 'Empty', 'Common', array());
```

But `<vid>Link</vid>` tag is stripping. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 'Empty'. Also, your code is out of date.

```
<?php
include_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'test');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
if ($def = $config->maybeGetRawHTMLDefinition()) {
    $def->addElement('vid', 'Block', 'Inline', 'Common', array());
}
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
echo $purifier->purify("<vid>Link</vid>\n");
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. I've updated my purifier's library to 4.4.0, I've been using 4.3.0